# How to see which functions are weak-linked in an object?

Tags: c, weak-linking

Is there a way to see/capture weakly linked functions in an object?

I removed older library's linkage but since some are linked with weak-linkage, I can't capture all of the used functions.

Comment: Please only use the language-tag of the language you're actually programming in.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what do you mean? what's the correct way to tag a c/c++ question?

Comment: If you program in C then use only the C tag. Don't use tags for multiple languages unless your problem is about comparison between them. Remember that C and C++ are two *very* different languages, with very different syntax (though some is shared) and widely different semantics. And as many will remind you, there is no such languages a "C/C++". There's *either* C, *or* C++.

Comment: Why is this tagged with the `hyperlink` tag?

Comment: The question is about a C feature that is used by C++ too. Hence we are in the shared ground for this question. But I'll still remove the extra tag if that can bother people.

Comment: Try `objdump -h` on the object file. The weak symbols will be in its own section with the discard flag.